# Prove $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{2}{\Delta t} \left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\Delta t}}\right)\right) = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, normal-distribution

Given 
$$\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{2}{\Delta t} \left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\Delta t}}\right)\right) 
$$

with $\Phi$ standard normal CDF, how can I prove the limit to be equal to $0$?

My attempt focused on the L'Hospital's rule but I can't exactly get the result. I also thought that since $\Phi$ is a CDF, its values are bounded between $0$ and 1, and maybe I could use this information somehow. Any hint?

Comment: $\Phi'(t) = \cdots$ and apply the chain rule.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule is fine. Any reasonable estimate of the size of the tail gives an alternative approach. Bounded between $0$ and $1$ is not directly useful, we need to know $1-\Phi(\dots)$ is small.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Could you please elaborate/answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\Phi(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x x^{-s^2/2}\,ds$$
$$\Phi'(x) = ...$$
(use the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus))

Comment: Well $\Phi$ is a CDF for the std Normal, so if I calculate the derivative I should get the std Normal PDF which is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$?

Comment: @Puzzle, right. Now, use L'Hôpital (and the chain rule).